# selecting from responsive dropdown list in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

How can I make a responsive dropdown list to select an item from the list and echo some value? I don't want to bind dropdown to any model. I have written following simple code to implement this but it is not working.

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id','', array(1=>'USA',2=>'France',3=>'Japan'));
if ('#country_id' === 1)
echo "Thank You";
else if('#country_id' === 2)
    echo "merci beaucoup";
else
echo "arigato";
?>
```

Dropdown is behaving correctly but I am not able to select an item from the drop down list. How can I correct my code?

Comment: #country_id it's a jQuery sintax.. you need to control it with javascript. Are using you jQuery?

Comment: ok can you give an example of how can I control it with javascript? Yes I am using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country_id').change(function(){
          var selectedId = $(this).val();
          alert($(this).val()); // Get what you want
    });
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/enn9H/